# Fit an equation in document

Tags: math-mode

I have a big equation that is not fitting in one column.My code is shown below

```
  \begin{equation}
\left[\max\left(D_{i, j}^{-x} T, D_{i, j}^{+x} T, 0\right)^{2}+\max \left(D_{i, j}^{-y} T, D_{i, j}^{+y} T, 0\right)^{2}\right]^{1/ 2} \\ =\frac{1}{F_{i, j}}
\end{equation}
```

my output is as shown
[image]

The equation is highlighted.How can I fit in one column

Comment: use `multline` from the amsmath package and add linebreaks (`\\ `) at suitable points (after the = presumably)

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{multline}
 \left[\max\left(D_{i,j}^{-x} T, D_{i,j}^{+x} T, 0\right)^{2} \right.\\
 \left. +\max \left(D_{i, j}^{-y} T, D_{i,j}^{+y} T, 0\right)^{2}\right]^{1/2} =\frac{1}{F_{i,j}}
\end{multline}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works.Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

I have adding `geometry` package, the option `twocolumn` and the same fonts of your picture with the packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

Here there is a new version.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{equation}
\left[\max\left(a, b, 0\right)^{2} +\max \left(c, d, 0\right)^{2}\right]^{1/2}=\frac{1}{F_{i, j}}
\end{equation}
where $a=D_{i, j}^{-x} T$, $b=D_{i, j}^{+x} T$, $c=D_{i, j}^{-y} T$ and
$d=D_{i, j}^{+y} T$.
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: no, please no not `\resizebox`.

Comment: Scale manually, it is just luck that the fences match in size here. Also I'd move the alignment point to `[&` on the first line

Comment: @daleif You are authorized to edit my code :-). My students have just delivered the written examination to my class.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is not into my code `\resizebox` and you have +4 upcomment. It's inexplicable to me.

Comment: @Sebastiano as you know (or could see in the history), you completely changed your answer, your first answer simply took the one line equation and scaled it to fit the column. Given that you changed your answer following that comment why do you say it is imexplicable?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/432ff0c1-d879-4cf1-a489-81c687491174/view-source

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's inexplicable because I edited it after a few minutes. I didn't know there was a chronology; but where can you see it from? Thank you.

Comment: your first answer had been there for some time when I commented and you changed it some time after that.  the "edited 25 minutes ago"  link under each  post shows the full edit history and the text of each version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I saw the review list and there's a link to it. I hope now that my response has improved. Greetings.

Answer (score 3):

How about you assign `m_1` and `m_2` for the two maxes, like this:

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \left[\max\left(m_1\right)^{2}+\max \left(m_2\right)^{2}\right]^{1/ 2} = \frac{1}{F_{i, j}} \text{, where}\\ 
        m_1= \{D_{i, j}^{-x} T, D_{i, j}^{+x} T, 0\} \text{ and } m_2 = \{D_{i, j}^{-y} T, D_{i, j}^{+y} T, 0\}\\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}\\
\lipsum[3-9]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the image, you're an unfortunate user of IEEEtran or similar class that mixes Times for text and Computer Modern for math.

I have three proposals; I'd prefer the last one. In all of them I removed the wrong `\left` and `\right` commands.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
\bigl[\max(D_{i, j}^{-x} T, D_{i, j}^{+x} T, 0)^{2}
\\
+\max (D_{i, j}^{-y} T, D_{i, j}^{+y} T, 0)^{2}\bigr]^{1/2}
=\frac{1}{F_{i, j}}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[1][1-2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\smash[b]{\frac{1}{F_{i, j}}}
&=\bigl[\max(D_{i, j}^{-x} T, D_{i, j}^{+x} T, 0)^{2}\\
&\qquad+\max (D_{i, j}^{-y} T, D_{i, j}^{+y} T, 0)^{2}\bigr]^{1/2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[1][1-2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\smash[b]{\frac{1}{F_{i, j}^2}}
&=\max(D_{i, j}^{-x} T, D_{i, j}^{+x} T, 0)^{2}\\
&\qquad+\max (D_{i, j}^{-y} T, D_{i, j}^{+y} T, 0)^{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're bold and decide to use Times *everywhere*, then the formula fits.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
\bigl[\max(D_{i, j}^{-x} T, D_{i, j}^{+x} T, 0)^{2}
+\max (D_{i, j}^{-y} T, D_{i, j}^{+y} T, 0)^{2}\bigr]^{1/2}
=\frac{1}{F_{i, j}}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[1][1-2]
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{F_{i, j}}
=\bigl[\max(D_{i, j}^{-x} T, D_{i, j}^{+x} T, 0)^{2}
+\max (D_{i, j}^{-y} T, D_{i, j}^{+y} T, 0)^{2}\bigr]^{1/2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[1][1-2]
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{F_{i, j}^2}
=\max(D_{i, j}^{-x} T, D_{i, j}^{+x} T, 0)^{2}
+\max (D_{i, j}^{-y} T, D_{i, j}^{+y} T, 0)^{2}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*

\end{document}
```

[image]